# "Plate" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning

Can I use plate for a sheet of paper? I'm not going crazy, in fact I read a sentence as follows:

> ..."And, like a fool, I presented you with that little piece of information on a ***plate***"

The little piece of information was actually on a **paper**. So, can I replace paper with plate? This is the first time I've heard this actually, "plate-paper."

Comment: Note that "plate" can have many different meanings, and you do not present enough context to reliably differentiate.  In this case it *appears* to have a metaphorical meaning as described by *tchrist*.

Answer (score 13):

No, this is a metaphor. At fine restaurants, any little thing you request will be presented to you on a fancy plate.

The OED has:

> III 27. b. *colloq*. ***to hand (also give) (something) to (a person) on a plate*** and variants: to give (something) to (a person) in such a way that little or no effort is required on their part; to present (something) without it having been asked or sought for; to present (something) in a complete or fully accomplished form.

Comment: "Platter" is also an extremely common metaphor in this context, especially "silver platter"s. Probably a similar origin, or of a Victorian butler delivering the newspaper, mail, calling cards, etc., on said silver platter.